# How can I check a php file for undefined functions?

Tags: php

Calling `php -l` checks the syntax of a php file.

Is there a way to check for undefined functions? **I don't need it to work with functions defined at runtime *nor* with dynamic calls**.

**Calling the file obviously won't work**: I need to check the whole file, not only the branch that gets executed. See the follwing example.

myfile.php:

```
function imhere () {}
```

main.php:

```
require_once 'myfile.php';

if (true) {
    imhere();
}
else {
    imnhothere(); // I need to get a warning about this
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "check for undefined functions"? Check for _calls to functions_ which are undefined? Also, what do you mean by "functions defined at runtime"? Custom functions defined using `function x() { ... }`? - as in, only include built-in PHP and extension functions when checking?

Comment: @JaniHartikainen it should check recursively the included files of course.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try using `is_callable`. this will give warnings at runtime. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php

Comment: @UdaySawant I don't need it at runtime, I need to parse the files from command line, just like I would do with `php -l`

Comment: Have you tried integration testing?

Comment: Open it in soome advanced IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse PDT, ZendStudio or whatever clever.It will tell you what is undefined.

Comment: @liquorvicar uh? I need it to work with existing projects, adding unit tests all over the place is definitely not an option.

Comment: I didn't say "unit tests" deliberately because I don't think unit tests will solve your problem. You could use higher level tests like integration test or even web tests. And btw it is often possible to get tests in place for an existing project (although it can be hard).

Comment: @liquorvicar oh. Could you point out what you mean with "integration test" or "web test", then?

Comment: They are both much higher level tests than unit tests but can work in a similar way and can be run against large chunks of your app. It would be easier to weedle out undefined functions etc (even dynamically defined or called functions): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_tests

Comment: @liquorvicar I'm sorry, I had seen that page, and it still says generically to "test" stuff, but it doesn't tell anything about which instruments I can use, which is the whole point of this question.

Comment: Ok I've posted an answer as there's a bit too much info for a comment!

Answer (score 2):

Checking for undefined functions is impossible in a dynamic language. Consider that undefined functions can manifest in lots of ways:

```
undefined();
array_filter('undefined', $array);
$prefix = 'un'; $f = $prefix.'defined'; $f();
```

This is in addition to the fact that there may be functions that are used and defined conditionally (through includes or otherwise). In the worst case, consider this scenario:

```
if(time() & 1) {
    function foo() {}
}

foo();
```

Does the above program call an undefined function?

Comment: That's why I explicitly said I don't need to check for special cases like your first example.

Comment: The second example instead should give no warning, since I also said it should check every branch, regardless (added an example).

Comment: @Lohoris You didn't explicitly say not to check for Jon's first example. You explicitly said not to check for functions *defined* at runtime, not dynamic function calls like in Jon's example.

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax only need to scan the current content of the php file, but check for function defined or not is something different because functions could be defined in the required file.

The simplest way is just to execute the file, and undefined function will give you a `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ....`.

Or you may want [this](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/).

Comment: ...*if* you happen to hit the code path which has the call to the undefined function.

Comment: Of course it won't work, because I need to check for the whole file, not just the part of it that gets executed... (@Jon exactly)

Answer (score 0):

Following comment tennis I thought I would wrap up some thoughts into an answer.

It seems like what you might need is some higher-level testing (either integration or web testing). With these you can test complete modules or your whole application and how they hang together. This would help you isolate calls to undefined functions as well as a host of other things by running tests against whole pages or groups of classes with the relevant includes statements. You can PHPunit for integration testing (as well as for unit-) although I'm not sure that would gain you that much at this point.

Better would be to investigate web-testing. There are a number of tools you could use (this is by no means intended to be a complete list):

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which I believe can hook into PHPUnit
- [SimpleTest](http://www.simpletest.org/), not sure how well maintained this is but I have used it in the past for simple (!) tests
- [behat](http://behat.org/), this implements BDD using Gherkin but I understand it can be used to do web-testing ([behat with Goutte](http://blog.phpdeveloper.org/?p=446)